# How to disable powermail javascript files and js libraries including validation?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-4.5

I want to disable jquery and javascript come from powermail 2.x

Any Ideas, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to disable javascript file in powermail try this in the Constants

```
plugin.tx_powermail {
    settings {
           javascript {
                    addJQueryFromGoogle = 0
                    addAdditionalJavaScript = 0
                   powermailJQuery >
            }
     }
}
```

if you want to disable js validation try this constant

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.validation.client = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

In TYPO3 6.2 and above you can remove each unwanted item of PowerMail's JS and CSS files separately. Use all or some lines of the following TypoScript in your TS-Setup:

```
#
# TS SETUP:
#

page.includeJSFooterlibs  {
    # prevent PowerMail from loading jQuery itself
    powermailJQuery >

    # prevent PowerMail from loading additional JS files
    powermailJQueryUi >
    powermailJQueryUiDatepicker >
    powermailJQueryFormValidationLanguage >
    powermailJQueryFormValidation >
    powermailJQueryTabs >
}

page.includeJSFooter {
    powermailForm >
}

page.includeCSS {
    # prevent PowerMail from loading CSS files
    powermailJQueryUiTheme >
    powermailJQueryUiDatepicker >
}
```